Social commentary in "In the Graveyard" by Chekhov
Within "In the Graveyard" (1884) by Chekhov, the narrator and his friends meet an actor in a graveyard. They initially mistake him to be a clerk, and are promptly corrected.

"No, an actor. Nowadays it is difficult to distinguish actors from clerks of the Consistory. No doubt you have noticed that. . . . That's typical, but it's not very flattering for the government clerk."

The actor is looking for the grave of a fellow actor. They find it in a state of disarray with the epitaph woefully reduced from "Never forgotten friend" to "forgotten friend". The actor remarks that money had been raised for a monument, but had instead been squandered.
There appears to be a dearth of analysis on this particular short story. From what I can gather, this piece appears to be some sort of social commentary about cultural degeneration, which might have some obvious interpretation to Chekhov's contemporaries. However, I am no expert on the zeitgeist and milieu of the Russian Empire under Alexander II so I do not want to speculate too much.
I was wondering if anybody could shine some light on the story as a whole, as well as the particular line quoted above. This story is extremely short and Chekhov is known for his metaphorical gun. What is Chekhov trying to say here? How might this have related to his own life? What is the historical context? Why might have they mistaken the actor for a clerk? Why is the consistory mentioned? Why would the misunderstanding be possibly offensive?
I love short stories like these that are cultural time capsules, but I wish I understood more about the context.

The Soviet 1975 scholarly edition of Chekhov’s works provides some context. The story was published in a humorous magazine Fragments – at this point of his career, Chekhov is a young comedy writer, and contemporary critics see his works as pure entertainment. With the publication of his later, more mature books, these earlier stories were retrospectively reassessed:

Now they were perceived as a deep revelation of the essence of life,
hidden under the mask of the comic. Their very "anecdotal nature" was
interpreted as a reflection of the inconsistencies of the existing
reality. […] P. N. Krasnov wrote in the article "Autumn Writers":

This general gloomy, twilight mood of Mr. Chekhov's stories is
conditioned by the vulgarity and boredom prevailing in our society.
The absence of public interests, the depressed, gloomy mood caused by
the stagnation and wait-and-see mood in our domestic politics, have
also affected individuals.


This seems to refer to Alexander III’s policy of "counter-reforms", characterized as reactionary. That contrasted with the high achievements of Russian culture.
Critics highlighted Chekhov’s use of contrast (often for comic effect). E.g. in the story, the tombstone inscription “never forgotten friend” due to decay turns to more realistic “forgotten friend”. This seems relevant for the “actor-clerk” pair. There’s something contradictory about an actor: lofty speeches and mere pretense. Consistory clerk’s job somehow combines spiritual matters and routine bureaucratic work (since Peter the Great the Church was under governmental control). Clerk’s work is orderly and boring – actor’s work is about emotions and art. (Chekhov at this point likes to employ “funny words” – so perhaps there’s a more technical reason to mention the consistory. Chekhov is a comedy writer!)
With the look of this alcoholic actor, we have another contrast: “a shaven, bluish-crimson countenance”, a bottle and parcel of sausages suggest more mundane associations than high art of tragedy. A respectable clerk, as the actor self-deprecatingly jokes, wouldn’t be happy about the resemblance. Additionally, hostile attitudes to theatre have a long tradition (also see Chekhov’s The Requiem). Again, there’s the contrast between the high and infinite and its finite real-life embodiment (in Russian, the term for this is “comic lowering”). However, through these contrasts, we seem to have an observation on the nature of life rather than a direct statement.
The monument money being spent on drink is a reference to real-life events. Nikolai Kireev, a talented actor and translator, died in May 1882. Then

On January 29, 1883, a concert was given at the F. A. Korsh Theater,
the proceeds from which were intended for the construction of a
tombstone monument to Kireev […]. However, in December 1883, the press
raised the question of whether the money raised had been used for its
intended purpose ("Where is the money raised for the monument to N. P.
Kireev?" – "News of the Day", 1883, No. 165 on December 12)

Did alcohol have any relation to Chekhov’s professional life? The commentary informs us that his publisher Nikolai Leykin wrote:

The day before yesterday, I returned from Moscow, met with the pillars
of my "Fragments" Chekhonte and Palmin, had a drink with them, gave
them parental guidance on what exactly is needed for the magazine, and
generally had a heart-to-heart talk.

That junket seemed to be quite successful since Chekhov later blamed the quality of his writing on a really bad case of hangover:

On October 1, Leikin wrote to Chekhov: “It’s strange that I didn’t
receive any response from you to my letter with the sending of the
sketch “In the Graveyard” <…> You explain the badness of the story “In
the Graveyard” by a hangover. Good God! Could a hangover really last
more than a week!”


I see. Thank you for the explanation. The story begins with a long paragraph about the grave of a man who had a habit of listening in on other people. Do you think there is any chance that this could have also been very overt commentary about the Okhrana?

@psubodiosa Seems unlikely. Soviet commentators are usually happy to point out something like that, but I can’t find anything. They also don’t report any problems with censorship for this story (all his stories had to pass state censorship)

Perhaps my imagination is a little too creative. The anthology I am reading has chosen a lot of stories about government officials which might have been suggestive in the wrong way.
